# Software to draw on the trackpad

Tags: software-recommendation, trackpad, magic-trackpad

I am asking about a software to draw figures and diagrams using the trackpad. I am already aware of Inklet, which works only in conjunction with other software like photoshop. I need another free stand-alone software that does not need other programs pre-installed.

Comment: as you are aware, it needs a app that accepts pen input. So what do you have ?

Comment: So basically you are looking for an application which combines Inklet directly with something like Pixelmator or Photoshop? Which benefits are you looking for in such an application compared to a combination of Inklet and the drawing application of your choice?

Comment: I tried inklet with a drawing app on the web, but did not have a good experience. I am asking for a free stand-alone application optimized for the trackpad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Notability](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/notability/id736189492?mt=12) is pretty optimized for the trackpad. Works well if you have an iPad stylus and use it on the trackpad too. Not to mention, iCloud sync and iOS apps to go along with it. Check it out if you haven't had a chance.

If that's not what you're looking for, then maybe [Pixelmator](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pixelmator/id407963104?mt=12) is more your cup of tea. It is fully optimized for the Mac as well.

To be honest, when you say "fully optimized for the trackpad," I think you'll find that there isn't much for that. The trackpad is great for a lot of things, but it certainly ain't no Wacom Bamboo tablet. In other words, it may be necessary to understand that the trackpad isn't specifically built for "drawing objects and shapes," although a Wacom tablet is. The programs listed above will certainly get you the desired results without much trouble.

One other thought... If you have an iPad, there are a slew of apps that will allow you to use your iPad as a mouse or a pseudo-trackpad. It may be worth while stopping by your local electronics store, picking up a $10 stylus for an iPad, and using that for drawing instead of the trackpad itself. One example of these apps is [Rowmote](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rowmote-remote-control-for/id300265786?mt=8). I've used it myself for a few years and love it.

Hope all this helps!

Comment: A new solution for using an iPad as a drawing solution is AstroPad. I've never tried it, but I've heard great things about it: AstroPad.com

Comment: what about Inklet 2?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Office 365 for Mac (requires Office for Mac 16.22.19021100). It supports usage of your trackpad as "touch" drawing - see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-your-trackpad-for-touch-drawing-in-office-365-for-mac-ccdba50d-f2b0-4153-80dc-38e557c9491c).

Will copy here main steps:

> 1. On the Draw tab of the ribbon, switch the Draw with Trackpad option to On. A drawing window appears onscreen.
> 2. Use two fingers to move the drawing window.
> 3. Use one finger to draw on the trackpad. You don't need to press down to immediately start drawing.
> 4. For greater location precision, press the Command key command button.
> 5. Press any key to turn off precision-draw mode.